# Running Docker Build from Jenkins, replace hardcoded Inputs in Dockerfile with parameters

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I want to run docker builds from a jenkis server, in case of this I want to specify some Inputs like passwords or path in the dockerfile as variables.

Is there a way to specify parameters for the docker build command and use this parameters as variables?

A case would be the mysql root password.

```
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password <<VARIABLE>>" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password <<VARIABLE>>" | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use --build-args ([link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options))

example:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ARG MY_ARG
RUN ... ${MY_ARG}
```

and then

```
docker build --build-arg MY_ARG=value
```